# How to return linq to sql query result in web service asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, linq-to-sql

I'm beginner in web service and want to write simple query with LINQ to SQL and return that query result with Web Service,write this code:

```
[WebMethod]
public  string LinqExample()
{
    string conn = "Data Source=REMOVETHIS";
    DataClasses1DataContext behzad = new DataClasses1DataContext(conn);
    string result;
    var query = (from p in behzad.CDRTABLEs
                 where p.name == "behzad".Trim()
                 select p).Take(1);

    return query.ToString();
}
```

But when I run that web service,I get this error:

[image]

How can I solve that?

Comment: Seems your connection string is incorrect.

Comment: @user2946329 yes,i change that connection string and work it.

Answer (score 1):

Three things:

1.) It seems your connection string is wrong, because there is a problem establishing the connection, not executing the query.

2.) You should not use `Take(1)`, [which returns an IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb503062(v=vs.100).aspx), but [`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb340482(v=vs.100).aspx). You use `Take` if you want to take the first *n* elements, but `First` or `FirstOrDefault` if you only want exactly one result element.

3.) If using `FirstOrDefault` so, you have to do a null-check on returning: `return query == null ? "" : query.ToString()`